# Make [blade] a synonym of [laravel-blade]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

Came across these two while tagging a question.

Please make [blade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blade) a synonym of [laravel-blade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-blade), as Blade is a templating engine of Laravel, and cannot stand alone.

This has not been requested before: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsynonym-request%5D+blade

I have looked at the top-voted questions for [blade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blade), and there isn't any confusion as [blade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blade) is commonly used together with the tag [laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel).

Likewise, [laravel-blade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-blade) is also commonly tagged together with [laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel).

Comment: `[blade]` is a very generic text string, which probably should not be used alone, at all, for a tag. It has a significant chance to be confused between different projects/uses, both now and in the future.

Comment: There are a small number of [questions tagged `[blade]` which don't appear related to Laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bblade%5D+-%5Blaravel%5D+-%5Blaravel-blade%5D+-%5Blaravel-3%5D+-%5Blaravel-4%5D+-%5Blaravel-5%5D+-%5Blaravel-5.1%5D+-%5Blaravel-5.2%5D+-%5Blaravel-5.3%5D+-%5Blaravel-5.4%5D+-%5Bphp%5D++-laravel+is%3Aquestion). There are still questions in that search that are related to Laravel, but it's a first pass at finding questions in `[blade]` which are not Laravel related.

Comment: While searching for blade-related questions on SO I came across this situation where I found there were not one but two tags for the Blade template engine. Even the tag descriptions are very similar. No doubt they're at least synonyms. As to the non-related questions @Makyen mentioned in their latest comment, even among those without any `laravel*` some are still related to Laravel's Blade.

Comment: Thinking of `[blade]` being generic, I agree with that. But to fix that instead of simply creating a synonym, we would have to either remove it or change its description and then move all questions to the proper tag, either `[node-blade]` or `[laravel-blade]`. What's the best/recommended way to resolve situations like this?

Comment: Ok! After this solo discussion, I found out this meta question was already resolved but not tagged properly. My bad for not double checking that before. Could some moderator add the `[status-completed]` tag to this question, please?

Comment: @GustavoStraube `[blade]` is still not a synonym of `[laravel-blade]` yet

Comment: @SamuelLiew Oh! Now I see the "pending" [on the right](https://i.imgur.com/qDfSjvo.png). Well, it seems there is no open voting for this, right?

Comment: @GustavoStraube see https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms